# Remove the text outside the brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i.e.

```
$text = 'remove this text (keep this text and 123)';

echo preg_replace('', '', $text);
```

It should output:

```
(keep this text and 123)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take anything found within the brackets, put it in a capture group and keep that only, like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*(\(.*\)).*$/', '$1', $text);
```

Comment: The regex: `/^.*(\(.*\)).*$/` does not work if there is more than one set of parentheses. e.g. it fails when you feed it this: `remove this text (keep this1) remove this too (keep this2)`

Answer (score 7):

This will do it: (and works with nested `()` as well)

```php
$re = '/[^()]*+(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))[^()]*+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
```

Here are a couple test cases:

```
Input:
Non-nested case: 'remove1 (keep1) remove2 (keep2) remove3'
Nested case:     'remove1 ((keep1) keep2 (keep3)) remove2'

Output:
Non-nested case: '(keep1)(keep2)'
Nested case:     '(keep1) keep2 (keep3)'
```

Comment: @David Thomas: I don't think the comment should be there to begin with. The block *should* highlight as PHP by default.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks! I'd tried to roll it back to before I started messing with it (because despite the preview the code wasn't being *shown* as code). But got stuck :(

Comment: Regarding the highlighting... Its true that you don't need the comment, but this helps force a specific language See: [Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971)

Answer (score 1):

Here the 'non preg_replace' way:

```
<?

$text = 'remove this text (keep this text)' ;

$start = strpos($text,"(") ; 
$end = strpos($text,")") ; 

echo substr($text,$start+1,$end-$start-1) ; // without brackets
echo substr($text,$start,$end-$start+1) ; // brackets included

?>
```

Note:
- This extracts only the first pair of brackets.
- Replace strpos() with of strrpos() to get the last pair of brackets.
- Nested brackets cause trouble.

Comment: This solution does not work. It returns `'(keep this text'` (it does not include the closing parentheses). It also fails when there are more than one set of parens.