# php regexp removing text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

If I have a string of the form:

```
$text='remove1  (keep1) remove2 (keep2) remove3';
```

Using the response

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293343/1154853

```
$re = '/[^()]*+(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))[^()]*+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
```

I get

```
(keep1)(keep2)
```

If I want to go from

```
$text='remove1  {keep1} remove2 {keep2} remove3';
```

to

```
{keep1}{keep2}
```

that is I want to change the delimiters, how do I change the given regular expression? I tried all sorts of combinations of changing ( to { but I couldn't get it to work. I find these reg exp pretty tough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parentheses `()`, you could use:

```
$re = '/(?:^|(?<=\)))[^(]+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '', $text);
```

**EDIT** For braces `{}`, use this variant:

```
$re = '/(?:^|(?<=\}))[^{]+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '', $text);
```

Note that these will fail - as all regex does - for nested structures.

Explanation

```
(?:        # non-capturing group start
  ^        #   start-of-string
  |        #   or...
  (?<=\})  #   look-behind: a position preceded by a } closing brace
)          # end non-capturing group
[^{]+      # any character except an opening brace, multiple times
```

The non-capturing group fixes the start of the match behind a closing brace or at the start of the string. The `[^{]+` matches every character up to the next brace. Effectively this matches everything in-between `{words}`.

See it: http://rubular.com/r/1Sp72TbHIi

**EDIT #2** Of course, thinking less complicated, this would also work:

```
$re = '/((?:\\\w+)?\{[^}]*\})/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
```

http://rubular.com/r/rPLMbCLbcq

Comment: When I test this, I don't get anything! Ah, I see, it works with ( and ) but I need { and }.

Comment: Then why is your first sample using parenteses?

Comment: because that was the response I found elsewhere on stackoverflow, that worked for (text) but I couldn't get it to work for {text}.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry. :) I've added variant #2.

Comment: This works! If I want to generalise the delimiters such that `remove1\hello{keep1}remove2` goes to `\hello{keep}` where do I need to add the string \hello?

Comment: @Geoff you know, you could have made that part of the question. Instead of `[^{]+` use `(?:(?!(?:\\\w+)?\{).)+`. No explanation for this one though, sorry. http://rubular.com/r/ClUy2nsVMI

Comment: I thought I'd ask a simpler question, and try to complete the rest myself. all the same, your code works.

Comment: @Geoff Asking complete questions is preferred. Next time. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8760/discussion-between-geoff-and-tomalak)

Comment: @Geoff I've added a much less complicated version, see modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the curly brackets:

```
$re = '/[^()]*+(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))[^()]*+/';
          ^^     ^     ^^           ^   ^^
                 Esc                Esc
```

The markings are where your delimiters are, only two need to be escaped with slashes. I believe this will work:

```
$re = '/[^{}]*+(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*\})[^{}]*+/';
```

Comment: This does the job. Now if I generalise and want to keep everything between `remove1 \hello{keep} remove2` such that I get `\hello{keep}` what do I need to edit then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$re = '/[^{}]*+(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*\})[^{}]*+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
```