# picking out text using regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have

```
$text='remove1  \solution{keep1} remove2 \solution{keep2 inner{text}} remove3';
```

and would like to use preg_replace to finish with

```
\solution{keep1}\solution{keep2 inner{text}}
```

I almost have a solution using

```
$re = '/[^{}]*+(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*\})[^{}]*+/';
$text = preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
```

But this does not keep the \solution in front. How can I solve this?

EDIT: \solution is meant to be a fixed string to be searched for, all the other text pieces are meant to be arbitrary.

Comment: \solution{keep1}\solution{keep2 inner{text}} , the second code line above.

Comment: Can I assume that the strings you want always start with `\solution{`? Can there be text after nested brace pairs, like this `\solution{keep2 inner{text} keep3}`?

Comment: I want to apply to a latex document, search for \solution{some text} and collect together all these expressions. Oh, to answer your comment, yes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regexp removing text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655914/php-regexp-removing-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I presume `remove1` etc. should be removed on the basis that they have whitespace separating them from the rest of the string components? I can't see any other rule to eliminate them. So your character class should be `[^{}\s]`.
- Also, although it won't break the regex engine, `[^{}]*+` and `[^{}]++` will slow it down enormously without making any difference. Use just `[^{}]*` or `[^{}]+`.

It is much easier to find all of the sequences you want in a piece of text and `join` them all together. This code shows the idea

```
$text = 'remove1  \solution{keep1} remove2 \solution{keep2 inner{text}} remove3';
$re = '/ \\\\solution (  \{ [^{}]* (?: (?1) [^{}]* )* \}  ) [^{}\s]* /x';

preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches);

$text = join($matches[0]);

echo $text;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
\solution{keep1}\solution{keep2 inner{text}}
```

Comment: this works, but where in the regexp is the \solution? How does it know to look just for this? Or am I missing something? Say for instance, I want to use this technique now for collecting together \question, what would I then do?

Comment: I realise that your code was not working as it picked up all \something{text} whereas I only want \solution{some text}.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell from your question exactly what you want. It turns out that `remove` can be any text, while `solution` is meant literally. There was no mention of `\solution` in your own regex so I asssumed it was any non-space sequence preceding an opening brace. I have modified my answer to do what I think you want now.

Comment: I have modified my answer again since you now say that `\solution{keep2 inner{text} keep3}` should match.

Comment: why the four backslashes. I appreciate it is something with escaping, but why four?

Comment: Because the string is processed twice. A PHP string like `'\\'` is just a single backslash, and when that is processed by the regex engine it serves only to escape the `s` in `solution` and so have no effect. Using `'\\\\'` results in a string of two backslashes, which are processed as an escaped backslash by the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the text you need and then implode.

```
preg_match_all('#\solution\{[^\}]*\}#msi', $text, $matches);
$text = implode($matches[0],'');
```

Comment: again, I get no output. But maybe I am testing your idea wrong. I have a test file of three  lines: `$text= ...;` then followed by your two lines, while echoing the final line.

Comment: I think the backslash of \solution needs to be escaped, but all the same if I do `preg_match_all('#solution\{[^\}]*\}#msi', $text, $matches);` then I get as output: `solution{keep1}solution{keep2 inner{text}`. Note the last } is missing.

Comment: @Aram the OP's original technique of using recursion is necessary to preserve nested braces.