# How to get an array in a string in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

If I have a string like this ,

```
$my_string="array('red','blue')";
```

How can I convert this to a real array ?

Example.    :

```
$my_array=array('red','blue');
```

Comment: For this purpose, you can use `eval` function... but its use is not reccomended.

Comment: @Rizier123, `array('red','blue')` is not a print_r output... i don't think its a duplicate question.

Comment: The bigger question is why you have such a string in the first place. If you want to serialise values, you should choose another format which is readily unserialisable; e.g. JSON.

Comment: @deceze I'm getting outputs from an app , only way I can communicate with the app is through strings , I want to check those strings are arrays if(is_array($string)) I have to run different set of functions, if its just a string I have to run something else , so will I be able to detect the string is a json object if I use json_encode in the app?

Comment: Yes, PHP source code is not an appropriate *data interchange format*. That's exactly what things like JSON were invented for.

Comment: Ok , thank you so mucj 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DO NOT USE `EVAL`. That is terrible overkill and very probably extremely unsafe.**

While this is not the *BEST* way of doing this (as mentioned in question comments), you can use this below function to do exactly what you need.

How it works:

It uses Regex to find and split the string based on these layouts, the array is split using `preg_split` which is a regex verson of the more popular `explode`.

Once split the array will have some blank values so simply use `array_filter` to remove these blank values.

so:

```
    // Explode string based on regex detection of:
    //
    // (^\h*[a-z]*\h*\(\h*')
    // 1) a-z text with spaces around it and then an opening bracket
    // ^ denotes the start of the string
    // | denotes a regex OR operator. 
    // \h denotes whitespace, * denotes zero or more times.
    //
    // ('\h*,\h*')
    // 2) or on '),(' with possible spaces around it
    //
    // ('\h*\)\h*$)
    // 3) or on the final trailing '), again with possible spaces.
    // $ denotes the end of the string
    // the /i denotes case insensitive. 

function makeArray($string){

    $stringParts = preg_split("/(^\h*[a-z]*\h*\(\h*')|('\h*,\h*')|('\h*\)\h*$)/i",$string);
    // now remove empty array values. 
    $stringParts = array_filter($stringParts);
    return $stringParts;
  }
```

**Usage:**

```
//input
$myString = " array('red','blue')";
//action
$array = makeArray($myString);
//output
print_r($array);
```

Output:

> Array (
>       [1] => red
>       [2] => blue
>   )

**Example 2:**

```
$myString = " array('red','blue','horses', 'crabs (apples)', '(trapdoor)', '<strong>works</strong>', '436')";
$array = makeArray($myString);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

> Array (
>       [1] => red
>       [2] => blue
>       [3] => horses
>       [4] => crabs (apples)
>       [5] => (trapdoor)
>       [6] => `<strong>works</strong>`
>       [7] => 436
>   )

Obviously the regex *may* need slight tweaking based on your exact circumstances but this is a very good starting point...

[Reference Question/Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293283/remove-the-text-outside-the-brackets)